# Nomenclature for per $2^n$?

Tags: notation, terminology, computer-science, percentages

We have the nomenclature **percent** to describe a number of something per hundred units:

Example: 1/2 = 50% (percent)

I wonder if there is a nomenclature for **per $2^n$** units? Like there are [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) for counting bytes (KiB, MiB, ...).

Example: 1/2 = 128 per 256 (?)